# How to print the multiples correctly?

Tags: c++

I am trying to display the multiples of a user-inputted number given 6 user-inputted numbers. I think I am sort of close, but I am stuck.

For example, if someone enters "4" and then their 6-number sequence is "23 45 12 16 51 8", it should return 12 16 8 because those are the multiples of the first inputted "4".

So far I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


//Display multiples of a number that appear within a sequence of numbers.

//E.g. input is looking for multiples of 5 in the following sequence of 6 numbers: 6 10 9 3 25 79 → output: 10 25

int main() {
  int userNum;
  int seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, seq5, seq6;

  cout << "Enter a number: " << userNum;
  cin >> userNum;

  cout << "Enter a sequence of 6 numbers: " << seq1 << " " << seq2 << " " << seq3 << " " << seq4 << " " << seq5 << " " << seq6;
  
  cin >> seq1;
  cin >> seq2;
  cin >> seq3;
  cin >> seq4;
  cin >> seq5;
  cin >> seq6;

  int sequence[] = {seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, seq5, seq6};

  int total;

  for (int sequence[] = seq1; i < 6; i++) {

    if (i % userNum == 0) {
      return total;

    }


  }
  cout << "Multiples in the sequence are: " << total;

}
```

Comment: Note: Your program has undefined behavior because you read the uninitialized variables `seq1`...`seq6` when you print them before entering values into them.

Comment: Instead of `return total;`, what about `std::cout << i << ' ';`? But your loop is all wrong as @PaulMcKenzie pointed out. `for(int i : sequence) { if(i % userNum == 0) std::cout << i << ' '; }` would probably work.

Comment: `for (int sequence[] = seq1; i < 6; i++)` -- I bet you won't find any `for` loop in the book you're using that looks like this.

Comment: What looks like is happening here are attempts to guess what the correct C++ syntax is in order to get the desired result. C++ is too complicated. Attempting to guess the correct C++ syntax, for something, is unlikely to produce the right guess. The way to figure it out is to consult the appropriate chapter in a C++ textbook that explains the relevant concepts; and C++ cannot be learned, one Stackoverflow question at a time. A good, quality textbook has no substitutes. The only way to learn how to do these tasks is with a textbook. Is there something in your textbook that's unclear to you?

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks im working on it now, im new as I mentioned earlier. You have helped me before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You print `userNum` and `seq1` to `seq6` before you've assigned values to them. That makes the program have *undefined behavior*.
- Your `for` loop has invalid syntax and you also `return` instead of printing the matching values. A fix could look like this:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      if (sequence[i] % userNum == 0) {
          std::cout << sequence[i] << ' ';
      }
  }
  ```
- You don't actually need the variables `seq1` to `seq6`. Just input directly into `sequence`. You can also use *range-based for loops* to make looping over the elements in `sequence` easier.

Example:

```cpp
#include <array>     // std::size
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int userNum;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> userNum;

    int sequence[6];
    std::cout << "Enter a sequence of " << std::size(sequence) << " numbers: ";

    for(int& num : sequence) { // a range-based for loop
        std::cin >> num;       // assign to all 6 elements in a loop
    }

    std::cout << "Multiples in the sequence are: ";
    for(int num : sequence) { // another range-based for loop
        if(num % userNum == 0) {
            std::cout << num << ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, this makes a lot of sense. When I am implementing it, though, `std::cout << "Enter a sequence of " << std::size(sequence) << " numbers: ";` throws an error. It says, "use of undeclared identifier 'size'". I do have `#include <array>' too.

Comment: @wockywoad Ah, ok, `std::size` was added in C++17. If you can't use C++17, you can use `(sizeof sequence / sizeof *sequence)` to get the number of elements in the array.

Comment: I appreciate you. I hope to one day be as knowledgeable.